# Passing values to nested attributes in python dataclasses

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I'm trying to create instances of a python dataclass that has nested attributes, when I pass an attribute that belongs to some nested one, it should replace the actual value with the provided.
Here my try:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Optional


@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class Attributes:
    correlation_id: Optional[str] = None
    routing_key: Optional[str] = None


@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class Metadata:
    workflow: Optional[str] = None
    workflow_state_id: Optional[str] = None
    attributes: Optional[Attributes] = field(default=None)

    def __post_init__(self):
        if self.attributes is None:
            self.attributes = Attributes()


@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class Message:
    version: Optional[int] = field(default=0)
    metadata: Optional[Metadata] = field(default=None)

    def __post_init__(self):
        if self.metadata is None:
            self.metadata = Metadata()


@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class Command(Message):
    ...


@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class SomeCommand(Command):
    name: str
    description: str


c1 = SomeCommand(name="awesome command", description="desc", routing_key='some key')
print(c1)
```

My expected response should be:

```
SomeCommand(version=0, metadata=Metadata(workflow=None, workflow_state_id=None, attributes=Atributes(correlation_id=None, routing_key='some key')), name='awesome command', description='desc')
```

But it doesn't work and shows the error:

```
TypeError: SomeCommand.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'routing_key'
```

Is it possible to do in Python dataclasses? if so, what should I change? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Neither `SomeCommand` nor `Command` nor `Message` derives from the misspelled `Atributes`.  How did you expect Python to find that link?  You would have to write your own `__init__`s to make that work.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really how data classes were designed to be used.

You can force `Message` to pass along the arguments to `Metadata` and for `Metadata` to pass along the arguments to `Atributes` by using:

```
from dataclasses import InitVar

@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class Metadata:
    workflow: Optional[str] = None
    workflow_state_id: Optional[str] = None
    attributes: Optional[Atributes] = field(default=None)
    correlation_id: InitVar[Optional[str]] = None
    routing_key: InitVar[Optional[str]] = None

    def __post_init__(self, correlation_id, routing_key):
        if self.attributes is None:
            self.attributes = Atributes(correlation_id=correlation_id, routing_key=routing_key)


@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class Message:
    version: Optional[int] = field(default=0)
    metadata: Optional[Metadata] = field(default=None)
    correlation_id: InitVar[Optional[str]] = None
    routing_key: InitVar[Optional[str]] = None

    def __post_init__(self, correlation_id, routing_key):
        if self.metadata is None:
            self.metadata = Metadata(correlation_id=correlation_id, routing_key=routing_key)
```

But I think this is sort of ugly.

(Is there a reason `Atribute` is misspelled, but `self.attributes` is spelled correctly?)

Comment: Thanks for a quick response, it was misspelled,  my mistake, thanks for noticing it.
It looks like I have no option to pass that value after the instantiation because it should be passed in runtime

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a complex initialization you can use a dictionary as `**kwargs` in your constructor. The initialization would be the following:

```py
c1 = SomeCommand(**{
  "name": "awesome command",
  "description": "desc",
  "metadata": Metadata(**{
      "attributes": Atributes(**{
          "routing_key": "some key"
      })
  })
})
```